# Can't find System.Deployment file Visual Studio 2017 OpenCV

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv

[image]I am having a problem with the project I downloaded that demonstrates openCV. I am using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac. My problem was that some references are missing, such as Emgu.CV.Ul.

Previously, I got the following error.

> The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.MatInvoke' threw an exception.

So what I did was Reference -> Edit Reference(for some reason, my VS does not have add reference) -> .Net Assembly -> locate those files and add.

But References indicates that System.Deployment is still missing. Where can I find this file? I can't find it online.

My VS does not have this file. Please look at the picture. System.Deployment can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN: *The [System.Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145029%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) namespaces contain types that support deployment of ClickOnce applications.*

It should be available for you to add as a reference in your project:

[image: System.Deployment reference]

Comment: Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Using VS2015 I had to do the following:

[image: Choose Add Reference]

[image: Select System.Deployment]

Comment: Click above to see images

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Describe the steps to do also in text form.